# Export Adobe Acrobat comments of a PDF into a text file?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have many PDFsf with 100s of annotations/comments in them, created through the free Adobe Acrobat Reader. By reading [this official guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/importing-exporting-comments.html#importing_and_exporting_comments), and skimming trough related pages, I see that I can "export" the comments in FDF files or XFDF format.

However, these files can't be opened by themselves without the original, from the first link:

> You cannot open and view FDF files or XFDF files on their own.

I would like to export the comments as a text file containing only the text of the comments.

Comment: You can open FDF and XFDF files on their own, of course. BUT they may not make much sense, because the comments depend on the base document to provide the actual context. So, if you are happy without the context, you can extract the text from the FDF/XFDF files (whereas XFDF would be an easier task).

Comment: @MaxWyss I'm not a programmer, so even hyper basic macro tasks I can't do, and given there is 1000s of notes, I don't really know. This is what a XFDF file opened with notepad++ looks like, only one comment:"font-size:10.5pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"
>41</span
></p
></body
></contents-richtext
><popup flags="print,nozoom,norotate" open="no" page="3" rect="514.407776,621.268738,694.407776,763.268738"
/></text
></annots
><f href="practica5.pdf"
/><ids original="8F84C2D4D7BE87E2214B2CA3907576" modified="794056D3F1054B9727BB9dfdf70BEF8"
/></xfdf

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks! How would you go to extract this things?

Comment: @Santropedro, I came across the same issue. Seems that the FDF/XFDF format do not record the text but pointers to the text in the original PDF file, so maybe the solution would be to use another free PDF viewer. Check this [Quora link](https://www.quora.com/Which-PDF-readers-can-export-highlighted-text).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit convoluted, but it works.
Follow the instructions here to export the comments and export them to an **XFDF** file:

1. Rename the file's extension to XML (i.e. if filename was "comments.xfdf", change its name to "comments.xml".
2. Open the XML file using google chrome.
3. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
4. Open a new Chrome window and navigate to this link (it creates a blank notepad):

   ```
    data:text/html,%20<html%20contenteditable>
   ```
5. Click on the white area and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
6. Select all (yes, again, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
7. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
8. Paste in a Word document.

**Note:** It may work with other browsers, but at least for me, when copying/pasting from Firefox, I'd end up with all the XML code in word.

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer @zx485

Comment: Steps starting at 4 didn't accomplish anything worthwhile for me, but steps 1-3 were good enough to format the XML in Visual Studio Code and I was able to extract the comments by selecting <contents> and then using "Select All Occurences of Find Match" (Ctrl + Shift + l)

Comment: Didn't (yet) try to analyze the XML or XFDF files, but from a quick run-through of the steps I only got to extract all comments **without** the comments' authors' names; so I can't see in the text file who said what (which would be nice to see...). Did you manage to also extract that detail?

Answer (score 0):

- Open the fdf file in Notepad++
- Replace `<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>` with `22222\133333` (don't
  forget to set search mode as regular expression and "matches newline")
- Put `33333` in the beginning of the document
- Put `22222` in the end of the document
- Replace `33333(.*?)22222` with an empty string
- Save file as .html document, open in browser
- Voila!

33333 and 22222 can be any sequence as long as it does not appear in your comments.